# Proper Lifecycle of Python Thrift Client Transport

Tags: python, thrift, thrift-protocol

What is the best practice for lifecycle of a  transport?

I'm finding that opening a transport per call is not effective. In particular the below code seems to spend ~5 seconds opening up the transport then ~300ms per call for my actual service invocation. The 300ms is more than acceptable.

Should I simply open the transport once per client and close at the end of the application? If I do that will I experience transient network disconnects? If I do, what client side exception(s) will be thrown?

My client batches request so that the client is not overly chatty. Meaning every 30s or so a message of a 1MB or so will be sent. Then approx ~2 mins later I will send a large message of size 15MB to 50MB

```
def make_transport_context(transport_context, rpc_type):
    # Make socket
    transport = TSSLSocket.TSSLSocket(transport_context.host, transport_context.port,ca_certs=transport_context.ca_certs,validate=False)
    transport.setTimeout(ms=transport_context.timeout_in_millis)
    # Buffering is critical. Raw sockets are very slow
    transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
    # Wrap in a protocol
    protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
    # Create a client to use the protocol encoder
    client = rpc_type.Client(protocol)
    return client, transport

@contextlib.contextmanager
def rpc_thrift_context(transport_context):
    client, transport = make_transport_context(transport_context,  DataRPC)
    try:
        transport.open()
        yield client
    finally:
        transport.close()
```